# Подключиться к Oracle из C++

Tags: oracle, c++, visual-studio

Необходимо подключиться к Oracle из C++. Покажите, плиз, работающий пример.

**Обновление**

Например, установил полностью Oracle Instant Client, у меня CentOS.
Cкачал файлики rpm и установил.

Пример лежит здесь: /usr/share/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64
Инслуды здесь: /usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64
Библиотеки здесь: /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64

Компилю: `gcc cdemo81.c -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64 -L/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64 -lociei`

Выдаёт ошибки:

```
cdemo81.c:(.text+0xd7): undefined reference to `OCIEnvCreate'  
cdemo81.c:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `OCIHandleAlloc'  
cdemo81.c:(.text+0x151): undefined reference to `OCIHandleAlloc'
```

Что делать?

Comment: @sitev_ru, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: И что Вы уже попытались сделать?

Comment: То, что выше описал: "Например, установил полностью Oracle Instant Client...", пробовал и другие примеры, наверное, не умею линковать. Делал это как-то раньше автоматом.